# Type Error in gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I am new with gulp and currently i am working on a project. I am having an typeError which states

> [11:18:00] 'serve' errored after 78 ms 
>     [11:18:00] TypeError: "listener" argument must be a function at _addListener 
>     (events.js:239:11)

My code is as followed :

```
gulp.task('serve',['sass'],function(){
  browserSync.init({
    server: "./dist"
  });
  gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss','src/scss/*.scss'],['sass']);
  gulp.watch('./dist/*.html').on('change',browserSync.reload);
});
```

Comment: Could just be the typo at browserSync.reaload  <-- reload

Comment: no sorry it is not i have checked sorry i mistyped in the code here on stackoverflow.

Comment: I assume you have var browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();

Comment: nope it is const browserSync = require("browser-sync).create();

Comment: I just did some reinstall of node and gulp and it is working fine now.Still don't know what caused the problem at the first place.